# jdbcTemplate setQueryTimeout value type

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8, jdbctemplate, query-timeout

I would like to know what is the type of value which we need to pass in `public void setQueryTimeout(int queryTimeout)` in `jdbcTemplate`. The document says

```
> Set the query timeout for statements that this JdbcTemplate executes.
> <p>Default is -1, indicating to use the JDBC driver's default (i.e. to
> not pass a specific query timeout setting on the driver). <p>Note: Any
> timeout specified here will be overridden by the remaining transaction
> timeout when executing within a transaction that has a timeout
> specified at the transaction level. @see
> java.sql.Statement#setQueryTimeout
```

Like to know if **queryTimeout** is `milliseconds`, `seconds` or `minutes`

Comment: it is strange how it doesnt specify whether it is seconds or milliseconds. You have to base on people's solutions on the internet. :)

Comment: @Young Emil `
Statement.setQueryTimeout` mentions the unit of input param

Comment: @mantri, I think the question targets `JdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout` and not that of `Statement` class.

Answer (score 5):

After checking the similar `setQueryTimeout()` from `java.sql.Statement` class, my guess is that they behave the same.

```
setQueryTimeout(int seconds)
```

A good way to start with similar issues is to check a working example on the internet. It helps a lot!

Comment: I voted up this answer because the function exist and I was able to code it with no errors. However, after implementation, it doesn't seem to timeout after the period.